# How to see SQL behind DMVs

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I see the SQL code behind DMVs in SQL Server?

DMVs are providing useful stats, but what are the tables involved in it which are fetching data?

Ex:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants
```

So what are the tables or where is data which is used by this DMV?

Comment: Even if you *can* see the source code for this - it will be using internal system tables that aren't otherwise accessible to you anyway - so this is really rather pointless....

Comment: That's correct but seeing others code/methods make you learn something. That's what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the object definition

```
select object_definition(object_id('sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants'))
```

But many of the DMVs (like this one) expose internal memory structures and aren't actually built on top of system tables.

So all you'll see is

```
select .... FROM OpenRowset(TABLE DM_EXEC_QE_GRANTSINFO) A
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I know to get what you're asking is to use Redgate [SQL Prompt](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/)

It will give you the definitions of all the system views, although it won't really do you much good as they make use of internal server objects that are not available to you.

However as an example, the DMV you cite above is defined as

```
create view sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants as
    select A.session_id, A.request_id, A.scheduler_id, A.dop, A.request_time, A.grant_time,
    A.requested_memory_kb, A.granted_memory_kb, A.required_memory_kb, A.used_memory_kb, A.max_used_memory_kb,
    A.query_cost, A.timeout_sec,
    Convert(smallint, A.is_small) as resource_semaphore_id, 
    A.queue_id, A.wait_order, A.is_next_candidate, A.wait_time_ms,
    A.plan_handle, A.sql_handle,
    A.group_id, A.pool_id, A.is_small, A.ideal_memory_kb,
    A.reserved_worker_count, A.used_worker_count, A.max_used_worker_count, A.reserved_node_bitmap
    from OpenRowset(table DM_EXEC_QE_GRANTSINFO) a 
go
```